# Issues with Conway Maxwell Poisson Family in glmmTMB

Tags: glmmtmb, underdispersion

I'm having issues running the the Conway Maxwell Poisson family (compois) in glmmTMB. I have under dispersed data (0.5). I am running a mixed model. 3 predictor variables, 2 random effects, n=1000.

If I choose any other family the model runs in a few seconds, with compois I ran it overnight and it did not finish. I then subset my data to n=30 and simplified the model to 1 predictor, 1 random variable, and it is still not finished after 30 minutes.

`mod.comp = glmmTMB(var1~var2+ (1|var3),
            family="compois",
            contrasts=list(var2="contr.sum"),
            data=dt_sample)

dt_sample <- structure(list(var3 = structure(c(12L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 13L, 4L, 17L, 6L, 13L, 7L, 19L, 14L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 14L, 5L, 11L, 8L, 5L), .Label = c("405", "411", "418", "501", "504", "508", "513", "519", "520", "602", "606", "609", "610", "801", "HB01", "HB02", "SBM01", "SBM02", "SBM03", "SBM04", "SBM05", "SBW01", "SBW02", "SBW03", "SM01", "SM02"), class = "factor"), var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No Action","Action"), class = "factor"), var1 = c(349, 21, 4, 5, 52, 445, 713, 18, 22, 74, 21, 22, 117, 713, 0, 32, 18, 38, 0, 1200, 18, 187, 66, 3735, 28, 423, 1716, 641, 144, 55)), row.names = c(9739L, 10603L, 9969L, 11149L, 2703L, 9645L, 4357L, 11259L, 4881L, 4273L, 11263L, 12343L, 4237L, 8789L, 12518L, 10599L, 11365L, 2699L, 12613L, 9173L, 11541L, 10773L, 9885L, 12183L, 10465L, 5819L, 9177L, 9661L, 10669L, 11435L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here:

- COM-Poisson evaluation is inherently slow, because the normalization constant has to be evaluated by brute-force summation;
- COM-Poisson is *especially* slow when the conditional distribution is overdispersed; in this case the number of discrete outcomes that have non-negligible probabilities is large, so the brute-force summation mentioned in the previous bullet point gets harder. (In the limit a $\nu \to 0$, as described in [this CV question about the `nu` parameter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249738/how-to-define-the-nu-parameter-of-conway-maxwell-poisson-in-spamm-package), the COM-Poisson converges to the geometric distribution.)
- with the sample data given here, the `phi` parameter for the dispersion (which is `1/nu`) goes to infinity (more precisely, the optimizer stops when `log(phi) = 25.333` or `phi = 1.01e+11`), i.e. the best solution for the conditional distribution is the geometric limit ...

It's probably best to fit a Poisson model first, check the level of overdispersion, and proceed with caution if it's large — in this case, $\hat \phi$ is 381 (!!)

```r
m0 <- glmmTMB(var1~var2+ (1|var3), family="poisson",
              contrasts=list(var2="contr.sum"), data=dt_sample)
sum((residuals(m0, type = "pearson"))^2)/df.residual(m0)
```

You can (1) speed up fitting a little bit by specifying parallelization (if you have multiple cores to work with; on my laptop, this example took about 20 minutes on 1 core and 3.5 minutes on 8 ...); (2) set some level of tracing output so that you can at least see that *something* is happening (and get a rough idea of when the fit will converge by monitoring the speed of decrease of the negative log-likelihood, which is the first number in the printed tracing output).

```r
system.time(
    mod.comp <- update(m0, family="compois",
                        ## verbose = TRUE,
                       control = glmmTMBControl(optCtrl = list(trace = 1))
                       )
)

options(glmmTMB_openmp_debug = TRUE)
system.time(
    mod.comp <- update(m0, family="compois",
                        ## verbose = TRUE,
                       control = glmmTMBControl(optCtrl = list(trace = 1), parallel = 8)
                       )
)
```